# PHP PDO Insert Query Produces Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi, i'm trying to run an INSERT query on my MySQL database using PHP PDO.

I place an array inside an add method:

**Instantiation of key value array:**

```
$agentList = array(
    'Sport'=>$_POST['agent-add-sport'],
    'Address1'=>$_POST['agent-add-addr1'],
    'City'=>$_POST['agent-add-city'],
);
```

**Function call with array as parameter:**

```
function addAgent($agentList)
```

Then I perform a bindParam binding the values in the key value pair to PDO variables:

```
$sqlStr = "INSERT INTO agents (Sport, Address1, City) VALUES (:sport, :address1, :city)";
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/Database.class.php';
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
$query = $conn->prepare($sqlStr);
$sqlStr->bindParam(':sport',$agentList['Sport'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStr->bindParam(':address1',$agentList['Address1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlStr->bindParam(':city',$agentList['City'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

But for some reason, I keep getting this error:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object"

I performed a `var_dump` on the `$query` variable right after: `$query = $conn->prepare($sqlStr);` to see if the sql string was successfully prepared. This is what it gave me:

> "object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(76) "INSERT
>   INTO agents (Sport, Address1, City) VALUES (:sport, :address1, :city)"
>   }"

Based off what it says in PHP's documentation for PDO prepare:

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

My `var_dump` produces an object, thus it prepared properly.

So I'm not sure what is wrong. If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: `$sqlStr->bindParam` should be `$query->bindParam`

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to use `bindParam` at all, you can pass the variables through `execute()` as an array.

Comment: @bassxzero Don't know how I missed that. Thanks! That did the trick